# Remove 'cross' duplicate result for double cross apply

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following data in a column:
`5;ABC|1;XYZ`

I would like to split the value on the '|' delimiter and then split every result on the ';' delimiter.
I have the following query, but unfortenately it gives me (sort of) duplicate results.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( Code VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    VALUES ( '5;ABC|1;XYZ' );

WITH Query AS
(
    SELECT T1.RowNum, SubSplit.Value FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) as RowNum, Split.Value FROM @MyTable
        CROSS APPLY SplitString(Code, '|') AS Split
    ) T1
    CROSS APPLY SplitString(Value, ';') AS SubSplit
)
SELECT q1.Value AS [Left], q2.Value AS [Right] FROM Query q1
INNER JOIN Query q2 ON q1.RowNum = q2.RowNum AND q1.Value <> q2.Value
```

The result is:
[image: Results]


But what I would like is:
[image: Needed]

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

For completeness, this is the SplitString function I use:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @input varchar(8000), 
    @delimiter varchar(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 0 a, 1 b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input, b) + LEN(@delimiter)
        FROM CTE
        WHERE b > a
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@input, a,
    CASE WHEN b > LEN(@delimiter) 
        THEN b - a - LEN(@delimiter) 
        ELSE LEN(@input) - a + 1 END) Value
    FROM cte WHERE a > 0
)
GO
```

Comment: Remove the `inner join` in the outer query and just select from query.  You are creating your own duplicate results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, That will give me the results in one column (spread out over multiple rows), I need to have the 5 associated with ABC in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another ROW_NUMBER in the outer query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63554/11)

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( Code VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    VALUES ( '5;ABC|1;XYZ|6;HXS|7;GGH' )

;WITH Query AS
(
    SELECT T1.RowNum, SubSplit.Value, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.RowNum ORDER BY SubSplit.Value) as RowNum1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) as RowNum, Split.Value FROM @MyTable
        CROSS APPLY SplitString(Code, '|') AS Split
    ) T1
    CROSS APPLY SplitString(Value, ';') AS SubSplit
)
SELECT q1.Value AS [Left], q2.Value AS [Right] FROM Query q1
INNER JOIN Query q2 ON q1.RowNum = q2.RowNum AND q1.RowNum1 = 1 AND q2.RowNum1 = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63554/11/0)**:

```
| Left | Right |
|------|-------|
|    5 |   ABC |
|    1 |   XYZ |
|    6 |   HXS |
|    7 |   GGH |
```

**Update:**

The use of the ROW_NUMBER() in the outer query will only work if the `Left` is less then `Right` when diong the string comparison. It will not work correctly for the `'6;123'` value. Therefore, there is a better approach by using an enhanced SplitString function as per below:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e6029/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @input varchar(8000), 
    @delimiter varchar(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 0 a, 1 b, 0 rn
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input, b) + LEN(@delimiter), rn + 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE b > a
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@input, a,
    CASE WHEN b > LEN(@delimiter) 
        THEN b - a - LEN(@delimiter) 
        ELSE LEN(@input) - a + 1 END) Value,
  rn
    FROM cte WHERE a > 0
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( Code VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    VALUES ( '5;ABC|1;XYZ|6;123|7;GGH' )

;WITH Query AS
(
    SELECT T1.RowNum, SubSplit.Value, 
    SubSplit.rn as RowNum1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Split.rn as RowNum, Split.Value FROM @MyTable
        CROSS APPLY SplitString(Code, '|') AS Split
    ) T1
    CROSS APPLY SplitString(Value, ';') AS SubSplit
)
SELECT q1.Value AS [Left], q2.Value AS [Right] FROM Query q1
INNER JOIN Query q2 ON q1.RowNum = q2.RowNum AND q1.RowNum1 = 1 AND q2.RowNum1 = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e6029/2/0)**:

```
| Left | Right |
|------|-------|
|    5 |   ABC |
|    1 |   XYZ |
|    6 |   123 |
|    7 |   GGH |
```

Comment: This is briljant. Thank you very much for your assitance.

Comment: I would change it a little bit, because with multiple source rows, this explodes on the inner join. I changed this `SELECT Split.rn as RowNum` with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) as RowNum`

Comment: [Good fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e6029/5) vs ['Bad' fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e6029/7)